# How to replace ZLibDeflater with ZLibEncoder

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm using the ZLibDeflater to compress a file, by reading it as a stream and transforming it:

```dart
new File(filePath)
   .openRead()
   .transform(new ZLibDeflater())
   .pipe(new File(gzipPath).openWrite())
   .then(...);
```

As the ZLibDeflater [is now deprecated](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/di9wZ-4HawE/TIV2XUWgcwEJ), how can I convert the code to use the new [GZipCodec](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/GZipCodec.html) class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [ZLIB](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io#id_ZLIB) :

```dart
new File(filePath)
  .openRead()
  .transform(ZLIB.decoder)
  .pipe(new File(zlibPath).openWrite())
  .then(...);
```

Comment: A converter is a StreamTransformer, too. that way is much better than mine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gave up to early, you can simply do it using the [`Converter.bind()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_convert/Converter.html#bind) method to transform a stream:

```dart
const GZipCodec()
    .encoder.bind(new File(filePath).openRead())
    .pipe(new File(gzipPath).openWrite())
    .then(...)
```